# Problemas creando o actualizando registros desde array

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Necesito ayuda. Estoy armando un sistema de carga de notas por materias por alumno.

Armé una planilla para cargar estas notas (angular) y una vez se terminaron de cargar, envío todo ese objeto para que sea procesado, pero cuando intento guardar esas notas (Busco en la base, si existe modifico, sino la creo), me genera todos los registros iguales.

El código es este:

```
var query = {};

query.delegacion = data.delegacion;
query.disciplina = data.disciplina;
query.periodo    = data.periodo;
query.nivel      = data.nivel;
query.anio       = data.anio;


for (var alumno in data.notas) {
    var id_alumno = alumno;
    for (var materia in data.notas[alumno]) {
        var id_materia = materia;
        var nro_nota   = data.notas[alumno][materia];

        query.alumno = id_alumno;
        query.materia = id_materia;

        Nota.find(query)
        .exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            if (result.data) {
                result.nota = nro_nota;
                result.save(function(err, doc) { });
            } else {
                var notas = new Nota();
                notas.delegacion = data.delegacion;
                notas.disciplina = data.disciplina;
                notas.periodo  = data.periodo;
                notas.nivel    = data.nivel;
                notas.anio     = data.anio;
                notas.alumno   = id_alumno;
                notas.materia  = id_materia;
                notas.fecha    = req.body.fecha;
                notas.nota     = nro_nota;
                notas.recupera = false;

                notas.save(function(err, doc) { });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Este es el objeto que recibo en NodeJS:

```
{ 
    delegacion: '57e3108ee0a5427810ed1dd1',
    disciplina: '589888d6dfae11da7c38c22e',
    periodo: '58a67d7798f945ea6928b055',
    nivel: '58a67278038397c566181428',
    anio: 2017,
    notas: { 
        '584878b97d60ab072930fba9': { 
            '58ae61d38f89a5574c28bdd4': 8.5 
        },
        '57e4393fcc6f162d3166925e': { 
            '58a71819fc82f69b0e1cf70b': 10,
            '58ae61d38f89a5574c28bdd4': 7.5 
        } 
    } 
}
```

[image: Objeto de Alumnos/Materias/Notas]

Entiendo que se puede manejar con promesas, pero no me llego a dar cuenta muy bien como implementarlas.

Desde ya, les agradezco cualquier ayuda me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pasas la variable query para hacer el find en Nota, solo debes de pasar el id_alumno y id_materia, porque como lo tienes declarado estas esperando encontrar el documento con todos los parametros:

```
query.delegacion = data.delegacion;
query.disciplina = data.disciplina;
query.periodo    = data.periodo;
query.nivel      = data.nivel;
query.anio       = data.anio;
```

También te sugiero pases a una función la parte de crear Nota, le pasas los parametros del query solo id_alumno y id_materi, nro_nota y usas un callback:

```
function agregarNota(query, nro_nota, callback) {
        Nota.find(query)
            .exec(function(err, result) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                if (result.data) {
                    result.nota = nro_nota;
                    result.save(function(err, doc) { });
                    return callback(true)
                } else {
                    var notas = new Nota();
                    notas.delegacion = data.delegacion;
                    notas.disciplina = data.disciplina;
                    notas.periodo  = data.periodo;
                    notas.nivel    = data.nivel;
                    notas.anio     = data.anio;
                    notas.alumno   = id_alumno;
                    notas.materia  = id_materia;
                    notas.fecha    = req.body.fecha;
                    notas.nota     = nro_nota;
                    notas.recupera = false;

                    notas.save(function(err, doc) { });
                    return callback(true);
                }
            });
    }
```

Creo que el problema esta en la variable de query, así pasa tu query a mongodb:

```
{ delegacion: 'delegacion',
  disciplina: 'disc',
  periodo: 'periodo',
  nivel: 1,
  anio: 2017,
  alumno: '57e4393fcc6f162d3166925e',
  materia: '58ae61d38f89a5574c28bdd4' }
```

Si prefieres dejar dentro del for loop la función de buscar Nota, la variable nro_nota puede mutar, tómalo en cuenta.

Comment: Osea, si la porcion de código que se utiliza para guardar/crear el registro la paso a una funcion, podría resolver el problema de que se generen 3 registros iguales? (Cada llamada a la funcion sería independiente una de otra!!

Comment: No, cuando contruyes tu query para pasarlo a la función de Notas.find(). Solo pasa los parametros de id_alumno y id_materia, resto de parámetros como delegacion, disciplina, etc, no van en el query. Solo si quisieras encontrar ese documento exactamente, pero por lo que entendí no es el caso. Lo de la función es como la sugerencia de usar código ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Usa código ES6 en lo que más puedas para que puedas aprovechar las numerosas novedades que te ofrece la versión más moderna del lenguaje. En primer lugar, **nunca utilices** `var` **como variable de control si vas a referenciarla en un callback** simplemente porque no funcionará como piensas.

JavaScript es un lenguaje asíncrono, los callbacks no se ejecutan de forma secuencial en el código, si no en paralelo, haciendo bastante posible que cuando el callback sea ejecutado el bucle ya haya terminado y siempre referencias al último registro cada vez. Puedes leer sobre closures para tener una idea más detallada al respecto.

Otro consejo es que **siempre modularices tu código**, siempre, por más pequeño que sea. Identifica responsabilidades, delégalas, **divide tu aplicación en capas**, cada una con una única responsabilidad. Por ejemplo, toda la lógica con base de datos **debe estar aislada del resto** y servir solo como un **servicio** para cuando se necesite traer datos de la base de datos.

Tu código, se ve así usando ES6:

**Router handler**

```
let notasRepository = new NotasRepository();

for (let alumno in data.notas) {
  for (let materia in data.notas[alumno]) {
    let nota = data.notas[alumno][materia];

    notasRepository.createOrUpdate({
      delegacion: data.delegacion,
      disciplina: data.disciplina,
      periodo: data.periodo,
      nivel: data.nivel,
      anio: data.anio,
      fecha: req.body.fecha,
      materia,
      alumno,
      nota
    })
    .then(doc => {
      // tienes disponible cada documento creado o actualizado
    });
  }
}
```

**NotasRepository**

```
export default class NotasRepository {

  updateOrCreate (params) {
    let where = (
      ({ delegacion, disciplina, periodo, nivel, anio, alumno, materia })) =>
      ({ delegacion, disciplina, periodo, nivel, anio, alumno, materia })
    )(params);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      Nota
        .find(query)
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc) {
            doc.nota = params.nota;
            doc.save().then(() => {
              resolve(doc);
            });
          } else {
            where.materia = params.materia;
            where.alumno = params.alumno;
            where.fecha = params.fecha;
            where.nota = params.nota;
            where.recupera = false;

            Nota.create(where).then((doc) => {
              resolve(doc);
            });
          }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Soy programador de php y esto surgio como una necesidad de evolucionar un poco y comencé a programar en NodeJs desde los miles de cursos que encontré online. En el medio salio ES6 y bastante me cuesta entenderlo.
Pero, ¿Puedo incorporar solo pequeñas porciones de código con ES6 o tengo que pasarlo todo a ES6?
Gracias

Comment: No es necesario portar todo a ES6, solo las partes necesarias, aunque yo te recomiendo escribir todo en ES6+ usando Babel. Es como usar PHP7, hay ventajas considerables que puedes aprovechar.